# Selenium - Https issue with PhantomJS and Proxy Auth with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, automation, phantomjs

ok so my goal is to connect to https website through proxy that requires authentication without any human interaction.

**solution #1: Firefox**

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "IP")
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PORT)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

*the issue:* once the browser opens, it open the auth popup for username and password.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('balbla')
```

doesn't work, no response at all.
also no luck with changing the proxy to

```
http://username:password@ip
```

**solution #2: PhantomJs**

with phantomjs i managed to make the authentication in the code:

```
service_args = [
    '--proxy=https://IP:PORT',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    '--proxy-auth=USERNAME:PASSWORD',
    ]
br = webdriver.PhantomJS(PATH,service_args=service_args)
br.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

*the issue:* i can't surf to any **https** website, for example I'm trying get into **https**://www.gmail.com, i get empty page.
the proxy is working with https for sure(doubled checked manually).

adding

```
'--ssl-protocol=any'
```

not working as well.

I'm using selenium with python under Linux env. looking for any solution that will help me work it out.

thanks a head.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's a little late :) - but basically remove the https from the proxy and set the proxy type to https i.e.:

```
service_args = [
    '--proxy=IP:PORT',
    '--proxy-type=https',
    '--proxy-auth=USERNAME:PASSWORD',
    ]
```